Как разрешить проблему с зависимостями, при использовании разных ресуров? Nest can't resolve dependencies
Я начинающий fullstack разработчик, делаю бэкенд для сайта с фильмами
У меня есть ресурсы User и Auth
В Auth я хочу использовать сервисы из User
Погуглив я пришёл к следующему:

Нужно экспортировать UserService в user.module.ts
В auth.module.ts у меня есть imports: [
UserModule
]
В сервисе auth я пишу constructor(
private readonly userService: UserService
) {}
Мне необходимо использовать этот сервис в сервисе и контроллере Auth

Приложение не падает с ошибкой и успешно запускается
Но при запуске тестов я получаю такую ошибку:
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthController (AuthService, ?). Please make sure that the argument UserService at index [1] is available in the RootTestModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
- If UserService is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
- If UserService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UserService */ ]
  })


